# Code inside script tags not running in MVC3 Application (Razor View Engine)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

The code inside the script tag in my application contains all the code that makes AJAX calls, validation and even a jqgrid. I started off with the problem - the jqgrid not rendering at all on the screen - and then I found that no method inside the script is getting called and if any method is called with a click event or something else, it throws an error telling that it's not a defined property. What could be my problem?

1. I am not using any layout page so I copied the references from the master page to the page under question itself. It didn't work.
2. All the other pages in the application also have jqgrid and they are all rendering properly.

**SOLUTION:**

The script's open tag had `language="jscript" type="text/jscript"`. Once I changed both to `javascript` everything was fine.

Comment: Did you looked at the console? Any error, 404 for library script files or such?

Comment: I am not that familiar with Javascript. :(

Comment: If you are using chrome, press F12 and in the window that pops up, select console tab and see what's written there in red.

Comment: Sadly, I run this application only in Internet Explorer. Will see what it says in Chrome and get back to you.

Comment: Mathew, there are no errors in the console tab of the Javascript console.

Comment: can u put some example code?

Comment: Please can you post sample code demonstrating the problem? Is the code visible in the page source? What doctype is the site (HTMl 5, XHTML 1.1 transitional etc.)? What type is the script (is there a type attribute on the tag) and does it have the attribute runat="server"? Above all, post code.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do that. :( But the issue is solved BTW. It was all a small mistake on my part. Thanks for trying to help, people! :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies, but are you waiting for the DOM to be rendered before running your script?

$( document ).ready() ?

Comment: I don't get you.
I have the $(document).ready() part in the script but I don't know what I'm doing. Can you elaborate about what you meant?